# Clearing a class instance with a member that has a deleted assignment operator

Tags: c++

I wanted to clear / reinstansiate a instance of a class using the assignment operator, but some members in that class have their assignment operator deleted. So when i try to assign it to a new instance it keeps its old values.

Heres a example:

```
#include <cstdio>
class C
{
    C operator= (const C&) = delete;
};

class B
{
public:
    int x = 0;
    C c;
    B& operator=(const B& other)
    {
        return B();
    }
};
int main()
{
    B b;
    b.x = 5;
    b = B();
    printf("%i\n", b.x); // prints 5, should print 0
    return 0;
}
```

Is there some simple workaround for this without writing a method that clears all of its members? Why does this happen?

Comment: `return B();` is an error and should fail to compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

Your current implementation of `operator=()` is fubar.

```
B& operator=(B const &other)
{
    x = other.x;
    return *this;
}
```

you should also test for self-assignment, before you do anything, though, since copying members can be quite expensive:

```
B& operator=(B const &other)
{
    if(this != &other)
        x = other.x;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: B& operator=(const B& other)
    {
 return *this;
    } gives me the same result

Comment: @rbwxgf if that statement is true for the function `main()` you showed in your question then your compiler is broken.

Comment: @rbwxgf edit your question and show the entire code.

Comment: @rbwxgf — your new version of the assignment operator doesn’t assign a value to`x`, so the value of `x` doesn’t change. That’s the point of this answer: the original version didn’t, either. Read the code in the answer carefully and compare it to your code.

Comment: I am a idiot. Yeah was somewhat hoping to avoid having to write assignments for all the members but theres no way around it. Not even sure what i was thinking with this.

Comment: @Swordfish — I took the liberty of removing the test for self-assignment for your code to make it absolutely what the solution is.

Comment: @PeteBecker I hope it is still absolutely what the solution is ;-P

Comment: @Swordfish -- whoops, that was supposed to be "absolutely **clear**". The test isn't needed here, although it's often appropriate.

Comment: @PeteBecker "The test isn't needed here, although it's often appropriate." thats why its included in my answer. most beginners don't even think about it.